# print command adding \n to everything in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, printing, xcode7

I thought I would start from scratch at learning to to build ios apps with the new xcode 7, upon following a tutorial which involves using print(message) the preview to the right of the screen shows the printed text but with an added \n. For example if I wanted it to show "Hello World", the preview would show "Hello World\n".

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I apologise for how stupid this might look, I just want to do everything right from the beginning to avoid problems further along, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.0, `print` has been redefined to work like `println` in Swift 1.0. You can eliminate the new line with `print(..., appendNewLine: false)`

**Edit:** apparently those language gods at Apple decided to change things again. The proper syntax, starting with Xcode 7 Beta 6 and including Xcode 7 GM is now:

```
print(..., terminator: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

So that's how the `print` message now works. It replaces the old `println` command by default. If you don't want the added newline, you have to say so (`appendNewLine:` parameter). You might want to consider reading the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs5printurFq_T_